# How to work with multiple recordsets out of one procedure from SQL Server in vba

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql, dao

I have linked a MS Access frontend to SQL Server (and somehow regret that decision). Now I have a bunch of procedures with a complex but similar `WHERE` part but different `SELECT DISTINCT` so I would like to combine them to a single procedure like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable1 INNER JOIN @tblFromFunc()
SELECT * FROM myTable2 INNER JOIN @tblFromFunc()
```

and a predefined table-valued function `@tblFromFunc` which will handle my `WHERE` just once. Hope for better performance and to make maintenance easier.

That works fine on the SQL Server an I even can get the first of this two independent results (just tried two of them) visible in MS Access by using `DAO.QueryDef` and `DAO.Recordset` in vba.

I found this description of `.NextRecordset` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193483.aspx), in short as vba:

```vb
DIM rst as DAO.Recordset
SET rst = functionConnectServer("NameOfSp")
booNext = True 
intCount = 1 
With rst 
Do While booNext  
    Do While Not .EOF 
        Debug.Print , .Fields(0), .Fields(1) 
        .MoveNext 
    Loop 
    booNext = .NextRecordset  
    intCount = intCount + 1 
Loop 
End With
```

but if I used it in Acceess 2010, I got the response, that somehow `.NextRecordset`is not supported anymore. So I cannot move to the second recordset, to be honest, I am even not sure, if that second recordset reaches my frontend.

Any hint would make me happy and I am even open to total different strategies for this problem.

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Access shows the complet first recordset with debug.print, stops and highlights at `booNext = .NextRecordset` and shows the runtimerror 3251,:  not supportet for this kind of operation.


End With

Comment: You are not assigning *rst* to anything. What is `New rst as DAO.Recordset`?

Comment: @Parfait: Jep, sorry, you are right, New, shoud be Dim and I just cut away the function, that handels the connection to the server. So ther is an additional line like `SET rst = functionConnectToServer("nameOfSpOnServer")`

Comment: I removed my answer as it applied to ADO and not DAO. Apologies.

Comment: @Wein.MC, Your answer lies in the link you gave.  You have to make sure you create a `Dim wrkODBC As Workspace` and a `Dim conPubs As Connection`.  Then you have to set the `dbUseODBCCursor`.  All of that linkage is not trivial and is needed so you can grab the next set of data.  (If you are doing that... then you need to add the code to your question.  Plus the error message would help too.)  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

While the DAO method requires specific objects to work with compound SQL statements, consider an ADO connection where you assign to [NextRecordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/nextrecordset-method-ado):

```vb
' REFERENCE Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.* Library
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_connection=yes;"
rst.Open "EXEC myStoredProc", conn

' FIRST RECORDSET
With rst
    Do While Not .EOF 
        Debug.Print , .Fields(0), .Fields(1) 
        .MoveNext 
    Loop 
End With

' SECOND RECORDSET
Set rst = rst.NextRecordset()

With rst
    Do While Not .EOF 
        Debug.Print , .Fields(0), .Fields(1) 
        .MoveNext 
    Loop 
End With

rst.Close()
conn.Close()

Set rst = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
```

While you may not be able to loop through many resultsets, you can place loop in a defined function and call it after each `Set`:

```vb
Function RetrieveData(rs As Recordset)
    With rs
        Do While Not .EOF 
            Debug.Print , .Fields(0), .Fields(1) 
            .MoveNext 
        Loop 
    End With
End Function

Sub DatabaseProcess()
    ...
    rst.Open "EXEC myStoredProc", conn

    ' FIRST RECORDSET
    Call RetrieveData(rst)

    ' SECOND RECORDSET
    Set rst = rst.NextRecordset()
    Call RetrieveData(rst)

    rst.Close(): conn.Close()   
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```